# Problema al conectar postgresql con laravel

Tags: laravel, postgresql

Tengo un problema para realizar la conexión entre laravel y postgresql, en el archivo .env para la parte de la base de datos tengo los siguientes datos:

```
DB_CONNECTION=pgsql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=5433
DB_DATABASE=candyucab
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=123456
```

Ya he creado la base desde pgadmin, y he verificado que los datos en el archivo .env se encuentren correctamente escritos.

Al momento de ejecutar el comando `php artisan migrate` en la terminal obtengo el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
También en el archivo php.ini he eliminado los comentarios para la sección de

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
```

¿Alguien podría darme una pista de cual es el problema?

Comment: el puerto no es 5432?

Comment: Al parecer solo es problema del puerto, asegúrate de que postgres ocupe el puerto **5433** ya que generalmente y por defecto se instala en el puerto `5432`

Comment: ¿Estas seguro que tienes el postgresql escuchando en 127.0.0.1 con el puerto 5433? verifica si el sockets esta abierto con el comando telnet telnet 127.0.0.1 5433

Comment: Si no as cambiado el puerto por defecto de postgresql, entonces
intenta cambiar el puerto de `DB_PORT=5433` a `DB_PORT=5432`